# Request-URI Too Long': URI length exceeds the configured limit of 2048 characters

Tags: akka, playframework-2.6

I had this configuration , i use play 2.6 and i cant use Netty and POST

```
 play.server.akka{
    http.server.parsing.max-uri-length = 16k
    http.client.parsing.max-uri-length = 16k      
    http.host-connection-pool.client.parsing.max-uri-length = 16k      
    http.max-uri-length = 16k
    max-uri-length = 16k
}

akka.http {
  parsing {
    max-uri-length = 16k
  }
}
```

But   throw this exception
akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(play-dev-mode)] Illegal request, responding with status '414 Request-URI Too Long': URI length exceeds the configured limit of 2048 characters

Comment: Perhaps this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891598/5194337

Comment: No I dont use that enviroment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play 2.6, URI length exceeds the configured limit of 2048 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249694/play-2-6-uri-length-exceeds-the-configured-limit-of-2048-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're running in dev mode, add the `akka.http.parsing.max-uri-length=16k` configuration setting to the command line:

```
-Dakka.http.parsing.max-uri-length=16k
```

Comment: In dev mode i had PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("play.akka.dev-mode.akka.http.parsing.max-uri-length" -> "4096") in sbt and it works . But how i can do in prod (not in dev mode ) ?

Answer (score 1):

From my original Post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63390208/1029251

This took me way to long to figure out. It is somehow **NOT** to be found in the documentation.

Here is a snippet to put in your `application.conf` which is also configurable via an environment variable and works for **BOTH** dev and prod mode:

```
# Dev Mode
play.akka.dev-mode.akka.http.parsing.max-uri-length = 16384
play.akka.dev-mode.akka.http.parsing.max-uri-length = ${?PLAY_MAX_URI_LENGTH}

# Prod Mode
akka.http.parsing.max-uri-length = 16384
akka.http.parsing.max-uri-length = ${?PLAY_MAX_URI_LENGTH}
```

You can then edit the config or with an already deployed application just set `PLAY_MAX_URI_LENGTH` and it is dynamically configurable without the need to modify commandline arguments.

```
env PLAY_MAX_URI_LENGTH=16384 sbt run
```